# What is correct jQuery syntax for background-image and parameters

Tags: jquery

i have really gotten enjoy jquery, but sometimes getting the syntax just right is a down right pain.

I am working on this bit of script which is already in place and working:

```
jQuery ('#bnr-home').css ('cssText', 'background-image:url(/sites/default/files/images/cosmic-banner-imgv2.jpg)!important;');
```

I want to add the background-position: bottom parameter to the above script. I have added so many variations with quotes and semicolons, trying to append and - just can get it correct.

Does anyone know the correct syntax?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: May be like this : `jQuery('#bnr-home').css('cssText', 'background-image: url("/sites/default/files/images/cosmic-banner-imgv2.jpg")!important;background-position: bottom;');` ?

Comment: Hi Swati - this one seems like it would make the most sense, but the background-position is not being executed.

Comment: I got it to work with your help.

Comment: sorry, hit return.  I remove the quotes within the url like this:
jQuery('#bnr-home').css('cssText', 'background-image: url(/sites/default/files/images/cosmic-banner-imgv2.jpg)!important;background-position: bottom !important');